# The 'g' in one chapter title results in a higher distance to the next chapter in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm using LuaLaTeX. My table of contents looks like:

[image]

When I remove the 'g' at the end of Becoming it looks correct:
[image]

I'm using the 'book' template and the packages I use are:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.91in,paperheight=7.87in,inner=2cm,outer=3cm,top=2.2cm,bottom=3.7cm]{geometry}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{fontspec}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
```

What could be the issue for the table of content having the extra space between the second and third chapter title? How do I fix it?

```
\documentclass{book}%


\usepackage{tocloft}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\LARGE}%

%
\begin{document}%

\tableofcontents%


\chapter{IIIII}%
\label{chap:one}%

\chapter{IIIII gggg}%
\label{chap:two}%

\chapter{IIII}%
\label{chap:three}%


\chapter{IIII}%
\label{chap:four}%


\end{document}
```

Comment: in code you haven't shown you have set some strange line spacing, I can't guess what as normally descenders affecting space would mean baselineskip too small but your spacing does not look tight. As always, your question would be clearer if you provided example code

Comment: your package list is inconsistent `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%` can only be used with (pdf)latex but `\usepackage{fontspec}%` can only be used with lualatex or xelatex

Comment: Try loading the `amsmath` package in the preamble and replacing `\chapter{Imaine Becoming a Cat}` with `\chapter[Imaine \smash[b]{Becoming} a Cat]{Imaine Becoming a Cat}`. If that doesn't fix it, do please edit your query to reveal what's going on in your document.

Comment: To echo (amplify?) David Carlisle's observation: Since you're loading the `fontspec` package, you shouldn't be loading the `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages. Furthermore, there's no need to load the `textcomp` and `lmodern` packages.

Comment: @Mico 's `\smash` will probably fix it, or rather hide it, but something is very wrong if it's needed

Comment: I extended your fragment to an example which [makes this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwFv1.png) please add code that produces the output you show

Comment: you are clearly not using latin modern as font, that means that you are not showing everything that is relevant.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : I edited my code down to a minimal example and added it.

Comment: are those freely available fonts?, I don't have them

Comment: more exactly i don't have Pacifico, you load this but dont appear to use it, is it needed to show the issue?

Comment: As I had guessed earlier, changing `\chapter{IIIII gggg}` to `\chapter[IIIII \smash{gggg}]{IIIII gggg}` would appear to fix (or, as David has argued) hide the problem.

Comment: I simplified the example so it did not rely on non standard fonts and without unrelated packages

Comment: really  \LARGE table of contents entries??

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the OP had `\Large` but with lmodern that almost works, so I used `\LARGE` to show the effect. (but `\Large` is already very large for a toc entry)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : It's a free font from google https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Pacifico

Comment: @Christian possibly, but why load it here making your document stop with a fatal error when the font isn't used in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

unfortunately tocloft makes it easy to add font size changes but takes no precautions to make the spacing work.

Simplest here is to set `\lineskiplimit` to insist on even spacing

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}%


\usepackage{tocloft}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\LARGE}%

%
\begin{document}%

\begingroup
\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen % force baselinespacing
\tableofcontents

\endgroup


\chapter{IIIII}%
\label{chap:one}%

\chapter{IIIII gggg}%
\label{chap:two}%

\chapter{IIII}%
\label{chap:three}%


\chapter{IIII}%
\label{chap:four}%


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `tocloft` package adds hooks.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cfttocprehook}{\begingroup\LARGE}
\renewcommand{\cfttocposthook}{\par\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{IIIII}
\label{chap:one}

\chapter{IIIII gggg}
\label{chap:two}

\chapter{IIII}
\label{chap:three}

\chapter{IIII}
\label{chap:four}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are similar hooks for `lof` and `lot`.